# getting data from multiple tables through textboxes using join in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my search page I have two textboxs, "tf_Zip" and "tf_Designation" where I enter "Zip" and Designation of the user, and I have two models i.e below:

```
user's model 
id | name | user_Zip
1  | abc  | 10005
2  | mno  | 10005
3  | xyz  | 10005

profession's model
id | UserID | Designation
1  | 1      | Lead
2  | 2      | software engineer
3  | 3      | Lead
```

And I want that when I enter `user_Zip i.e 10005 in tf_Zip textbox and Designation i.e Lead in tf_Designation textbox` then it give me those users whose user_Zip is 10005 and Designation = Lead and user 1 and 3 are those users whose user_Zip is 10005 and Designation = Lead and I am using the below code:

```
def search
@user_zipdesignation = Profession.joins(:user).where('users.user_Zip' => params[:tf_Zip] 'and professions.Designation' => params[:tf_Designation])
end
```

In the code I am using two condition for user_Zip and Designation, but It gave me error below:

```
C:/Sites/MentorMentored1/app/controllers/search_controller.rb:32: syntax error, unexpected tSTRING_BEG, expecting ')' ....user_Zip' => params[:tf_Zip] 'and professions.Designation' ... ... ^ C:/Sites/MentorMentored1/app/controllers/search_controller.rb:32: syntax error, unexpected tASSOC, expecting keyword_end ...and professions.Designation' => params[:tf_Designation]) ... ^ C:/Sites/MentorMentored1/app/controllers/search_controller.rb:32: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting keyword_end C:/Sites/MentorMentored1/app/controllers/search_controller.rb:50: syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting keyword_end
```

I don't understand where I am missing ')' . Kindly help me, waiting for reply. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
def search
  @user_zipdesignation = Profession.joins(:user).where('users.user_Zip = ? AND professions.Designation= ?',params[:tf_Zip],params[:tf_Designation])
end
```

and watch your development log for SQl statements

Answer (score 1):

does this work?

```
def search
  @user_zipdesignation = Profession.joins(:user).where('users.user_Zip' => params[:tf_Zip],  'professions.Designation' => params[:tf_Designation])
end
```

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html

Comment: no its not working because it check only user_Zip condition and it should check both condition.